# How to extract number between two strings?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

I have a vector like below

```r
id < c("1250.3000488281_-57.882898769379_OilA")
```

I need to extract the number after the _ i.e -57.882898769379.

I tried something like this

```r
library(magrittr)
id_play %>%
    stringr::str_extract(.,"(?<=[[:punct:]])([0-9]+)(?=_Oil)")
```

Instead of getting -57.---- I get everything after the "." , i.e ""882898769379".

How do I exclude the lookbehind to not include the punctuation "."?

Answer (score 5):

An option with `sub` to capture the one or more digits after the `_`  and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*_(-?[0-9.]+)_.*", "\\1", id)
#[1] "-57.882898769379"
```

Answer (score 2):

Read it with `read.table`.  No regular expressions or packages are used.

```
read.table(text = id, sep = "_")$V2
## [1] -57.8829
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `[[:punct:]]` with underscore:

```
"(?<=_)(-?[0-9.]+)(?=_Oil)"
```

Comment: This works too!  What does the "-?" do before the [0-9.]+?  I tried adding the underscore but didn't work but works when you add this "-?"

Comment: @DilsherSinghDhillon: This means an optional `?` hyphen `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit()` and then extract the second element of each record.

```
vapply(strsplit(id, "_"), `[[`, character(1), 2)
```

Not as efficient as `sub()` but maybe less specialized knowledge of regular expressions required.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Simply add the punctuation characters in the middle

```r
id_play %>%
    str_extract(.,"(?<=[[:punct:]])([0-9,.,-]+)(?=_Oil)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to get everything between the underscores:

`stringr::str_extract(id,"(?<=_).+?(?=_)")`

`#[1] "-57.882898769379"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

`(?<=[!-#%-*,-/:;?@\[-\]_{}])[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?=_OilA)`

https://regex101.com/r/iznDc1/1

Explained

```
 (?<= [!-#%-*,-/:;?@\[-\]_{}] )      # Behind, an ascii punctuation
 [+-]?                               # Optional plus or minus
 (?:                                 # A valid, parseable, integer or float (non-exponent)
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?= _OilA )                         # Ahead, this literal
```